# Fancybox - Youtube Embed 100% while maintaining the Aspect Ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, fancybox

I am wondering if there's a way to have an embedded Youtube video open in fancybox and take up a certain percentage in width, say 100% or as big it will go while preserving the aspect ratio of the video contained within it.

I have:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: {},
            overlay : {
                css : {
                    'background' : 'rgba(230, 230, 215, 0.95)'
                }
            }
        },
        padding: 0,
        margin: 30,
        width: '90%',
        aspectRatio : true,
        autoSize: false,
        arrows: false,
        closeBtn: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible with some CSS and/or jQuery. You'll be working with your embed code, not with your Fancybox code. Check out this article: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php